# Removing cast shadow from Landsat 8

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, remote-sensing, classification, landsat-8

I've got Collection 2, level 2 Landsat 8 dataset which contain mountains. The problem is the cast shadows from the mountains, so that I can't classify these pixels well. These pixels have much lower values because of the shadows.

Is there any method to remove these shadows?

[image]

I'm using ArcMap, and I've already tried the Topographic Correction, but it wasn't successful.

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about ArcMap, QGIS or something else within this particular question.

Comment: One method that is used for clouds is to create a cloud mask and then fill in values for different time periods within the extent of that mask. You can use a similar approach with shadows.

Comment: There are several parallax (illumination angle) topographic corrections available for spectral data (eg., cosine model, C model, solar-canopy-sensor (SCS)+C model, empirical rotation model, Minnaert). So, ESRI solutions are not the end of the line. I would investigate and try a few then reformulate your question if they are ineffective. "ArcMap did not work" is not a very satisfactory conclusion to be presented here. Why did it not work? Did you try a variety of model parameters? There are also different magnitudes that "shadows" that can effect data, what was the accusation angle?

Comment: https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/fd6ed990984945d5a9827418e67f26df I've tried this toolbox for the correction, but the I got crash with every methods.